# Can I limit visibility of ol.interaction.select layer in openlayers on different resolutions?

Tags: openlayers

In my openlayers map I show layers only between two given resolutions (set with maxResolution and minResolution on the layer).

I would like to add this behavior to a selected feature as well. But ol.interaction.select does not have maxResolution and minResolution properties.

Styling fill to have a opacity of 0 when not between resolution-limits seems to be a visual solution but I would prefer to use an analogy of setting max- and minResolution on the layer.

Comment: Are you saying the vector layer doesn't support min/max resolution?  Is your code similar to http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/select-features.html?  Docs say it should work: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.layer.Vector.html.

Comment: Vector layer does support. I am looking for the interaction layer to have similar functionality.

Comment: What is an interaction layer?  You mean you want to disable the interaction at certain levels?  You can handle that with change:resolution handler (see https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.View.html).

Comment: When a feature is selected it will be placed on another "interaction layer", won't it? 
This ''layer" has it's own styling function etc

Comment: Yes, you are right.  It is called featureOverlay_ and is inaccessible and I see no indirect way of getting at it (possibly enumerating the map layers would work).   A custom style is the only option I see for you.

Comment: Actually, it is not called [featureOverlay] (https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/4e7f5582345433923113a7992d00a200208efab4/changelog/v3.7.0.md)
It is an [interaction](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html) instead of layer, but I guess in a way we can see it as a layer, just without the min/max-resolution props ;)

Comment: The internal layer is called `featureOverlay_`.